# Why can we add "a number of" before nouns?

Tags: grammar, nouns

In the following sentence:

> The city is populated by many people.

"many" can be replaced by something like "a great number of" (let us leave the perceived differences between the meanings of these two modifiers out of discussion):

> The city is populated by a great number of people.

I understand that this replacement does not change the object "populating the city" from the original "people" to a "number", but rather shows the ability of expressions in the form "[numeral] of" to provide information about the quantity of nouns they modify.

Is this ability due to some special qualities of nouns such as "number", "quantity", "fraction", &c., or is it just one usage of the preposition "of"?

Comment: In your second sentence, the object of *by* is *number* and *people* has become the object of *of*, so I think the premise of your question may need revisiting.

Comment: @choster I understand. I thought that, if you consider _a great number of_ as just another modifier like _many_, the object of _populated_ remains the same in the two sentences: _people_.

Comment: What object of populated do you mean?

Comment: 'Many' is a quantifier. So is 'a number of' (a compound, ie multi-word, quantifier). Both only premodify count nouns.

Comment: In the noun phrase "A number of people", "a number of" is not modifying anything; it's not even a constituent. "Number" is head of an NP with an _of_ PP as complement. So in the NP "a number of people", the head is the quantificational noun "number", which has the PP "of people" as complement.

Comment: There are a great number of questions along this line already.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot generalize it to nouns.

You can do it with [countable nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun).

You cannot put **a number of** before [mass nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun).

**A number of knowledge** is wrong, even though it is a noun.

Answer (score 3):

*CGEL* (*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*) has (at 3.3, p.349) a charmingly cumbrous term for terms like *a lot*, *lots*, *a great deal*, *plenty*, *oodles* and *a number* when these are used with *of NOUN*: it calls them **“number-transparent quantificational nouns”**. Let’s call them ***ntqn***s.

That is, although these terms are by syntactic form the heads of the noun phrases (NPs) ***ntqn*** of NOUN, the semantic head of the NP is taken to be the ‘oblique’, *NOUN*, the term which is the object of *of*, and it is this semantic head which governs agreement. An ***ntqn*** like  “*lot* is number-transparent in that it allows the number of the oblique to percolate up to determine the number of the whole NP.”

In other words, semantics trumps syntax<sup>†</sup>: the verb agrees with the sense rather than the form.

(Note, by the way, that ***ntqn***s are not always singular forms; the same phenomenon is observable with plural ***ntqn***s anticipating singular semantic heads:

> Oodles of chocolate **was** provided.  )

That of course merely names the phenomenon; it does not provide any sort of ‘rule’ governing what nouns can become ***ntqn***s. I'm afraid that the only ‘rule’ that's operative here is the ‘rule’ of common sense: the speaker’s commonsense notion of what she means, and the sense common to all her hearers that that’s how English actually works.

---

<sup>†</sup> Do not conclude from this that ***ntqn*** of is somehow ‘transformed’ into a syntactic quantifier like *many* or some. *CGEL* presents (on pp.351-2) “compelling arguments” against understanding ***ntqn*** of as a constituent.

Comment: We get so many of these questions that I’d make a [tag:number-transparent-quantificational-nouns] tag for it but for the sad circumstance that that it is too many characters in the tag. However, I’m unfamiliar with these these putatively compelling arguments for understanding these as constituents. They seem no different from pre-determiner quantifiers like *“some of the”* to me. I can’t tell the difference between a simple determiners like *some* and longer phrases like *“some of the”* and *“a lot of the”* and *“a number of the”* in terms of what they do to the agreement; to wit, nary a bit.

Comment: @tchrist CGEL compels because it says so.