# There "is" or "are" a wealth of opportunities?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is, quantifiers

Which is correct: "there ARE a wealth of opportunities" or "there IS a wealth of opportunities?"

Comment: 'Vague quantifiers' present an even greater problem than the more regular variety. 'A majority of the voters were male', with notional agreement, is almost certainly the preferred variant; [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=majority+of+the+voters+were%2Cmajority+of+the+voters+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmajority%20of%20the%20voters%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmajority%20of%20the%20voters%20was%3B%2Cc0) suggest this. But with 'vague quantifiers' such as 'a wealth of', the pull of formal agreement is stronger.

Comment: With your particular examples, [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+a+wealth+of+opportunities%2Care+a+wealth+of+opportunities&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20wealth%20of%20opportunities%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20a%20wealth%20of%20opportunities%3B%2Cc0) would seem to show that neither is considered incorrect, but that people keep changing their minds about which they like better. // But please include the research you’ve done . Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Worth looking at: [Why can we add 'a number of' before nouns?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342962/why-can-we-add-a-number-of-before-nouns/342994#342994).