# What is the proper verb form to use after "a breadth of [plural]"

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which of the following sentences is the correct conjugation:

1. A breadth of organisms *depends* on water.
2. A breadth of organisms *depend* on water.

I believe the subject of the sentence is singular, "a breadth," in which case option 1 would seem to be correct. However, whenever I say this sentence out loud it just sounds wrong. Further, one could compare these two sentences to the nearly identical "many organisms *depend* on water," or "a lot of organisms *depend* on water," where the plural form of the verb is clearly the correct choice.

Comment: Do you mean *A wide range of organisms depend on water*? *A breadth of organisms* isn't very idiomatic.

Comment: Nowadays, there is a choice according to many mature Anglophones. Is 'a breadth of' a non-bleached fuzzy quantifier taking logical agreement (they depend) or does one prefer to see it as unitary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["There is" or "There are" a large quantity of people?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245438/there-is-or-there-are-a-large-quantity-of-people) See also [There is or are a wealth of- opportunities](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412982/there-is-or-are-a-wealth-of-opportunities)?

Comment: Yes, your concept of breadth should determine singular or plural. Sentence one likely sounds funny because "organisms," a substantial four-syllable word, immediately precedes the verb. By the time your tongue gets to that fourth syllable, humble "breadth" has been near forgotten.

Comment: Better not to use "breadth"!  One option would be "a large variety."

Comment: I believe your initial conclusion was correct. It "sounds wong" because we hear the plural word "organisms" right before the verb. The distance from the actual subject fools your mind.

Comment: This is why people often get things like this wrong when speaking extemporaneously. It's hard for the mind to keep track of nested phrases like this.