# "The total number of votes given to each candidate in alphabetical order were as follows:..." or should that be 'was'?

Tags: verb-agreement

When the spokeswoman declared the results of the second ballot in the UK Tory leadership race, she said:" ...The total number of votes given to each candidate in alphabetical order **were** as follows:xxx,41;xxx, 46; ...".

Should the **were** be **was**?

Comment: This is surprisingly tricky. Even if we strip out the issue with *votes* being plural, something like "The salary for each position is as follows: <position> -- <salary>; <position> -- <salary>" is rather awkward . . . but "are" is much worse.

Comment: And why past tense? You'd normally say the results still stand in the present, right?

Comment: @JJJ Not necessarily, because the *giving* of the votes happened in the past. It's perfectly normal, and the formula used by returning officers in national elections.

Comment: She treats "number" as number-transparent, which means that the whole noun phrase takes on the number of the noun that is complement of the preposition "of", which in this case is the plural "votes".

Comment: please see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/342994/210913

Comment: Possible  duplicate  of
  possiblehttps://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students

Comment: possible duplicate  of
 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students  of

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "the total number of votes" can usually take either singular or plural aggreement, with different dialects splitting the usage differently depending on context. However, there is something else going on here. The predicate "given to each candidate" clearly requires that there are more than one "total number of votes". So plural is strongly indicated. While the construction is entirely idiomatic as written, there is an option available to make the plural choice more obvious. One could use *numbers* instead of *number*.

> the total numbers of flights by different airlines between two specific cities in the 
>   past month ...
>
> From [Chegg Study textbook Solutions](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/total-numbers-flights-different-airlines-two-specific-cities-im-past-month-discrete-contin-q34529227)

...

> the total numbers of bacteria in different samples tested ...
>
> From [Annual Report of the Storrs Agricultural Experiment Station ..., Issue 15](https://books.google.com/books?id=mZY_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22the+total+numbers+of%22&source=bl&ots=jDvHbJtfUW&sig=ACfU3U0SG7sM-Y7FEeL3y2FV7NVwJHLU3Q&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2qaH4gu_lAhWvna0KHaF9B_8Q6AEwB3oECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22the%20total%20numbers%20of%22&f=false)

[image]

From [Parliamentary Papers, House of Commons and Command, Volume 51](https://books.google.com/books?id=njITAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA108&lpg=RA1-PA108&dq=%22the+total+numbers+of%22&source=bl&ots=br0ry1xCGk&sig=ACfU3U0T7b2xOq4K2Rl06BxtTO4dA9UJjw&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiigNj3hu_lAhVCKa0KHZySBK04ChDoATABegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=%22the%20total%20numbers%20of%22&f=false)

Comment: Please link and attribute _properly_. Use say [NZ Penal Data for Boys](htt....=false). Then the outrageous address is masked.

Comment: Much more reader-friendly. For an upvote (at least one), is there any evidence to support '

The phrase "the total number of votes" can usually take either singular or plural aggreement, with different dialects splitting the usage differently depending on context.'?

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers are surprisingly incompetent grammarians when it comes to the subject-verb agreement, especially when it's spoken English. I suspect this is one of those cases where 'were' is erroneously used instead of 'was'.

Specifically, the grammatical number of the subject 'The total number of votes given to each candidate in alphabetical order' is determined by the singular 'number', but the speaker mistakenly felt that the plural 'votes' determines its grammatical number due to the rather long intervening participial phrase 'given to each candidate in alphabetical order'.

That said, 'were' could have been used in a different sentence:

" ...The total **numbers** of votes given to **the candidates** in alphabetical order **were** as follows:xxx,41;xxx, 46; ...".

Comment: 1 whatever native speakers say is grammatical (tchrist has established this elsewhere on this site) , 2 grammaticality is based on usage

Comment: @green_ideas Native speakers do make isolated mistakes. And those isolated mistakes cannot be considered established usage. The question is whether the OP's sentence is established as usage, which I highly doubt.

Comment: It is not  true that  whatever  native speakers or  write  is  grammatical.There must be  some standdard for  non-native  speakers or native speakers

Comment: the sentence in question demonstrates subject-verb accord, so what's the "mistake" ?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/342994/210913

Comment: the speaker said nothing "erroneously"... not all utterances in English allow for cut and dry examination based on simplistic textbook rules. native speakers make the rules, and again, whatever they say is inherently grammatical. the speaker shows a proficient knowledge of how to construct noun phrases and verb phrases, proficiency in adjective placement, etc, so when we disagree with her sense of S-V concord, suddenly she's displaying a profound ignorance of how her own language works?

Comment: It is  not  true that  native speakers  always  speak  grammatically  correct  sentences  though  correctness  is  established  by the  usage of  the  native  speakers  rather than  what  is  written in grammar  books.

Comment: @ JK 2  I  have  upvoted  your  answer. I think  you are  correct. I  follow  syntax  rather  than  semantics  for  verb  and  subject  agreement( concord)

Comment: +1 for the last point. The pertinent question is how to express the OP's intended meaning, and the OP needs to state several *numbers*, one number for each candidate. Hence "numbers of votes ... were", as in this answer's last para.

Answer (score -1):

A number  of  is  treated  as  plural  because  it  means  several  or  many.

The  number of is  treated  as  singular  because  it  refers to the  number1, 10, 1000 etc.

The use  of  each  candidate or  even  all  the  candidates can not  prevent  us  from using  the  singular  verb  was  in the  sentence

Here  is  a  link  which  shows the  use of the  number of

https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/a-number-of-and-the-number-of

I think the  correct  verb  required  in the  sentence  might  be  *was*.

> She  said,  the  total number  of  votes  given to  each  candidate in alphabetical  order  was  as  follows.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/342994/210913

Comment: please also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/502241/the-number-of-votes-was-or-were#comment1259239_502250